# Strange behaviour after upgrading to GORM 2

Tags: go, go-gorm

After upgrading to Gorm 2.0 I get a strange error that I cannot figure out. It worked fine under previous versions.

```
var foundUsers []models.User
err = db.Model(&models.User{}).Find(&foundUsers).Error
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cannot find users : %v", err)
}
```

Error:

```
cannot use db.Model(&models.User literal).Find(&foundUsers).Error (type error) as type func() string in assignmen
```

Comment: Strange, have you tried just not having the `Model(&model.User{})` bit, `foundUsers` already has all the information gorm needs to know what to query.

Comment: Actually, wait! You are assigning to `err `, but it seems that `err` is of type `func()` according to the error message. Can you post your code showing where/how you defined err?

Answer (score 1):

Your `err` variable seems to be declared as type `func()`, idk how this happened (missing code) but regardless you can shadow the variable like this, which would solve this problem:

```golang
if err := db.Model(&models.User{}).Find(&foundUsers).Error; err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cannot find users : %v", err)
}
```